# if and bitwise & on the same line

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I was browsing through an open source project and came across this python method. I am aware on how the & and << bitwise operators work, but I am not sure how the if else statement works in this case. I can say int = 2 and position is = 1 and the if statement results to 2 (10 base 2), but what does this if statement compare 2  to? and how would I evaluate to the else statement?

```
 def get_bit(int, position):
    if int & (1 << position):
        return '1'
    else:
        return '0'
```

Comment: This just tests if a specific bit is set, e.g. `get_bit(4, 2) == '1'`, whereas `get_bit(4, 1) == '0'` Though it is very bad practice to use a python keyword for a variable name `int`.

Comment: Note `4 = 0100`, note that also `get_bit(7, 2) == '1'` as `7 = 0111`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tests if the result is falsey.

In Python, values such as `False`, `None`, `0`, empty strings, empty lists, etc. are "falsey", while others are truthy. In this case, it's effectively comparing the result of the bitwise AND with zero.

```
if (int & (1 << position)) != 0: # same thing
```

Comment: Don't you mean not zero?

Comment: @achampion Yes, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The if statement checks the "truthiness" of the expression. For instance, if you had:

```
if some_expression:
    ...
```

That's equivalent to writing:

```
if bool(some_expression):
    ...
```

You don't have to call `bool()` explicitly, but there's relatively little harm in doing so if you want to. Some programmers consider it bad style, since it's not strictly necessary.

It's not necessary because every expression in Python has a truthiness value. The things that are false are:

- `False` (obviously)
- `None`
- 0 (as an int, long, float, or any other numeric type)
- the empty string, whether str or unicode (a distinction which mostly only exists in Python2.x)
- empty lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries, and other container types

Custom classes can also declare their truthiness by implementing [__nonzero__](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__).

So, in the case of your specific question, the "if" part of your if/else will be executed even if the expression evaluates to 2, since any non-zero int will be considered True in a boolean context.